# Replace path seperator csharp for matlab path

Tags: c#, matlab, c#-4.0, path

I am creating a small WPF program in VisualStudio 10, which plots a graph in matlab and then saves this graph to a file in a directory.

In C#, I first retrieve the current path with

> path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

After which I send it to Matlab with the MLApp package, to get matlab to save in the right directory.

> matlabExe.Execute("cd " + path + ";");
>   In which matlabExe is the MLApp.MLApp thingy..

However, because C# has this fancy way of saving paths with double backslashes (\\), matlab does not recognize the path! So, would be easy I thought, just do

> path.Replace(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);
>   But sad enough, that did not do the job! When adding a watch to the path, I saw nothing had changed after doing this replace..

I also tried to replace the double seperator 'manual' by doing

> path.Replace("\\", "/");

But no luck either.. How can i get this done? :(

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# uses the double \ as an Escape Sequence

if you look at the string in the debug window it will look like this

```
 "C:\\Program Files\\MatLab\\MatLab.exe"
```

but when the program actually uses the string it will look like this

```
 "C:\Program Files\MatLab\MatLab.exe"
```

So you doing need to do any path.replace it will take care of it on its own which is why your having trouble with it. If you want to make sure try this

```
  string path = "C:\Program Files\MatLab\MatLab.exe";
  int count = path.Count(s => s == '\');
```

count will be 3 even though in the debug window it will show 6.

**If matlab does not recognize the path there is another reason**

if you want show the exact path your trying to create and what the exact path C# is spitting out and I can help you

For more info see [Escape Sequences on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)